# Finding repeating patterns/images in images

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition, pattern-recognition

I've been looking around for some papers (or info) on this topic.

To avoid a misunderstanding: I'm not talking about finding a supplied pattern in multiple locations.

Repeating patterns can also be understood to mean repeating images.  The definition of pattern here isn't abstract.  Imagine, for instance, a brick wall.  The wall is composed of individual bricks.  A picture of the wall is composed of the repeating image of a brick.

The solution must preferably find the largest repeating pattern.  Large in this context can be defined two ways: pixel area or number of repetitions.

In the above example, you can cut the bricks in half.  In order to make a brick, you can rotate a segment and attach the halves.  While the complete brick is the largest repeating image in terms of pixel area, there are 2x more repetitions of half blocks.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I haven't been able to find any previous work.  I'm asking the community for either partially or directly-related leads.

Comment: What you are looking for is Periodic Textures. Please clarify if this periodicity is expected in the image plain or if perspective (or other) transformations are expected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A number of methods come to mind:

- Fourier Transformation of the image
- Wavelet Analysis
- Autocorrelation

I'd start with fourier analysis: Any shape repeating in a regular pattern in the image creates a very distinct spatial frequency spectrum: One major frequency and some harmonics.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I suggest searching for "Texture based segmentation". Take a look at this bibliography, for example: http://www.visionbib.com/bibliography/segment366.html